# VS Code Keybindings for Select All Inside Tag or Expand selection outwards?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext, emmet

Cant seem to find what I am looking for and maybe it doesn't exist yet? I have the sublime text keymap extension installed, but that along with VS Code / Emmet seem to be missing one of my all time favorite sublime shortcuts...

**Select all inside tags / Expand selection outwards**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

I assume you mean the *Expand Selection to Tag* command in Sublime?

In VS Code the built-in command *Emmet: Balance (outward)* does basically the same thing.  It selects content of a tag and then progressively includes the tag and works outward with each repetition.

You can create a custom keybinding for it as well in the preferences, for example

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+a",
        "command": "editor.emmet.action.balanceOut"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you will get is with the extension [expand-region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).

And since you are using Sublime Text Keymap extension try to import your Sublime keymaps.  See [release notes v1.23](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_sublime-text-keymap-extension) :

> The Sublime Text Keymap extension is now able to import settings from Sublime.
>   The first time the extension is launched, a prompt is shown that displays all your importable Sublime settings. If you want to import your settings at a later time, use the Sublime Text Keymap: Import Sublime Text Settings command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Maybe you will get lucky with the shortcut you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the built-in shrink and expand selection in VS Code. Although I prefer jodyfanning's *Emmet: Balance (outward)/(inward)* method for tags.

I have the emmet shortcuts on `Shift`+`Alt`+`J`/`K`. And the shrink and expand shortcuts on the default `Shift`+`Alt`+`◀`/`▶`.

Copied from [VS Code Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#:%7E:text=Shrink%2Fexpand%20selection,and%20Shift%2BAlt%2BRight):

> Quickly shrink or expand the current selection. Trigger it with
> Shift+Alt+Left and Shift+Alt+Right.
>
> Here's an example of expanding the selection with Shift+Alt+Right:
>
> [image]