# In VS Code, How Do I Select Opening HTML Tag, Closing HTML Tag and all the Things In Between?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact/">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
      Portfolio
      <!-- TODO: Make this a dropdown menu. -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Project 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Project 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Given something like the above, I want to select the opening `<nav>` and then also select the closing `<nav>`, including everything in between.

In other words, a shortcut key (Mac OS X) to select opening, closing and all the markup in between.

Comment: Holding down shift you can select where the blinker currently is to where you click.

Comment: Yeah...tx. I meant to just click in opening  and then ⌨️ shortcut to select from that  to closing . Not multiple clicks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485729/1363423 This works very well

Answer (score 1):

With the html that you have:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact/">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
      Portfolio
      <!-- TODO: Make this a dropdown menu. -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Project 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Project 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In VS Code, if you select the `<nav>` in the first line and then do the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

It should highlight the whole code block for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the search feature, enabling RegEx search mode [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499581/most-efficient-way-to-swap-for-in-vscode/56549660)

Here is the search string you can use:

```
<nav>[\s\S]*<\/nav>
```

Explanation:

1. Search for the specific characters: `<nav>`
2. Followed by zero-or-more (`*`) white-space (`\s`) and/or NON-white-space (`\S`) characters *(which includes newlines)*, and
3. Stopping when you reach `</nav>` (inclusive)

[See this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uOhvEP/1)